# Find and print the number of non-alphanumeric characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing a project and I'm having issues getting the `re.findall` to work properly. Here's the code this far (short and sweet):

```
pattern = ['^a-zA-Z0-9_']

results = re.findall(pattern, (str(lorem_ipsum))
print(len(results))
```

I'm getting a syntax error printing this way. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm crunched for time, and will be tweaking tomorrow when I have some more time.

Comment: The `results = ...` line is missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: Here is the full project:

Comment: import re

#Paragraph provided for search and replace

lorem_ipsum = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit-amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis velit ac nunc interdum tempor. 
Ut volutpat elit metus, vel auctor enim commodo at. Nunc quis quam non ligula ultricies luctus porta id justo. 
Quisque dapibus est ut sagittis bibendum. Mauris ullamcorper pellentesque porttitor.

Comment: Ut sit:amet ex nec dolor gravida 
porttitor. Proin at justo finibus justo vestibulum congue. Suspendisse et ipsum et ipsum eleifend dapibus a fermentum 
lacus. Vivamus porta nunc eu nisl sagittis, quis vulputate metus dignissim. Integer non fermentum nisl, id vestibulum 
elit.

Comment: Sed euismod vestibulum purus ut porttitor. Integer sit-amet mollis neque. Donec sed lacinia diam, ac finibus 
lectus. Mauris tempor ipsum nisl, vitae posuere est lacinia nec. Nam eget euismod odio.'''

#Using the findall function, get all of the instances of non alphanumeric characters in the string assigned to 'lorem_ipsum'
#Output to the console, the number of non-alphanumeric characters.  Hint:  use the len function


pattern = ['^a-zA-Z0-9_']

results = re.findall(pattern, (lorem_ipsum))
print(len(results))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket after lorem ipsum, you'll also need to turn your pattern into a raw string. essentially pattern must be a string not a list. We add the r in front to make sure that backslashes are considered literally rather than needing to be escaped.

```
pattern = r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]'

results = re.findall(pattern, (str(lorem_ipsum)))
print(len(results))
```

Comment: That moved me forward, but now I'm getting an unhashable type: list error. These RE's will be the death of me.

Comment: Added an edit to fix the unhashable type. This should now count the non-alphanumeric strings for you.

Comment: Also, I can't remember if _ is a special character in python regexp, so I escaped it but you'll have to test the pattern out to see if it actually needs escaping.

Comment: dang it! I had that before I added the (str(lorem_ipsum))). Thanks! works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need any regex to do this. Simply use [.isalnum()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalnum.htm)

```
text = "hello 23232@"

for character in text:
    if not character.isalnum():
        print("found: \'{}\'".format(character))
```

output:

```
found ' '
found '@'
```